# ProtoBuf.ServiceModel namespace missing in NuGet protobuf-net package for UWP application

Tags: uwp, protobuf-net

I would like to communicate to another application via WCF from my UWP app (Creators Update, 10.0; Build 15063). Is there a way that I can add the functionality to my app or is it not possible?

As I side note, it's also missing in a .NET Standard 1.4 project. In a NET4.0 project I can successfully reference it.

Comment: And I would have thought that this is a frequent issue. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately there are a few things preventing me having a solid answer here:

- I don't tend to use UWP
- I don't tend to use WCF

As such, I simply lack the knowledge of whether it works successfully, or what changes would be required to make it do so. Or even what voodoo is needed to make it compile. Or whether WCF on UWP supports the required extension points (some frameworks don't).

UWP is something that I aim to greatly improve support on in upcoming releases moving more and more towards a code-gen model. WCF, however... kinda isn't something I have huge plans to look at currently :/

If you have the knowledge to see what works and what doesn't: PRs are great!

Comment: UWP uses .NET Core. I am not sure yet but I thought WCF in .NET Core shouldn't be significantly different from the implementation in .NET Framework. That's why I was surprised to find the namespace missing in the NuGet package. If I have the time and skill I might have a look at the possibility of porting it.